# Specific type of Smoke Simulation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, smoke-simulation

I was trying out smoke simulation in cycles, though I couldn't get the specific type of Smoke I want. I want to create smoke for a drifting car (similar to burnout smoke but less). I searched the web but couldn't get one addressing this specific smoke simulation in cycles. I want to know what is needed for simulating that and how that function affects the smoke.[image]

Comment: I don't think you'll find "burnout smoke" in the options, but what specific characteristics do you need for your smoke? Can you [edit] your Q to add more details, maybe even a screenshot or a video link of an example?

Comment: Some best examples would be Ken Block's Gymkhana videos. For example https://youtu.be/_bkX5VkZg8U

Comment: Do share your opinions and tips, I would probably need more than one source, so I can have better experimental range and try out things faster.

Comment: I think _you_ need to come up with examples of what you want, so people can help you with the setup. Be a bit more specific, the video you shared is 8 minutes long, don't make us watch the whole thing... Check [ask] to learn how the site works.

Comment: Well, 4-5 minutes of it was burning rubber, full of smoke that I'm trying to simulate. And for examples and being specific, I already said it's going to drift, and now I added a picture if that helps for being specific, or if other kind of drift exists. However, if my question seem to treat "Burnout" smoke and "Drift" smoke as different, then it's because there are factors come into play in reality.

Comment: For example, if someone imagines a burnout, they picture a car with the rear wheels spinning with the car being stationary and as a result a lot of smoke is produced. While drifting that smoke amount would be reduced a bit. And in the initial stages of burnout and drifting, the smoke is not too high because the tyres are cold. For the huge amount of smoke that pictures show us are because the tyres are already warmed up enough to burn through the rubber easily.    So, because I'm animating drift, I'll need the smoke first. Then I can alter the density afterwards

Comment: Hmmmm very helpful people here....

Comment: This sounds like a rant. The more well formulated / specific the question, the higher are the chances someone will come up with a good answer. I'm not a blender expert, I'm just trying to help you write a better question so you get a solution to your problem. Take it easy, sometimes it takes a few days for someone to come up with a good answer.

Comment: I have specified the question already, if that's not specific then I can't go any simpler. And there's no reply which would have indicated that my problem is being worked on.  It will sound like a rant, but is that my face speaking it? No, so even if it does, doesn't mean could be that. However all caps work for that purpose better

Answer (score 1):

Smoke behavior is heavily impacted by the **temperature difference** between the smoke and the domain : if the smoke is hotter, it will go up (like smoke from a burning fire) ; if the smoke is colder, it will go down (like mist, or nitrogen).

In the case of a drifting car, the "smoke" is probably more dust than smoke. By the way, it should be the same temperature as the domain (or maybe *a little bit* colder, to simulate the gravity).

This setting can be found in "Domain/Smoke/Temp. Diff.". I suggest starting with a really low negative value, like -0.0001.

Comment: Okay I'll play with those. However, I'm not going for Drift Race Smoke, more like cold tyre smoke which are very less relatively and usually increase if the tyre temperature starts getting higher. I'll be doing those for animation and shots for an upcoming hypercar which I designed. Will go in website and YT (probably). Anyways, thanks!